# Dual-booting Ubuntu 14.04 with Win 7 on a RAID 0

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 to dual-boot with my windows 7 in a RAID 0 array of 2 120gb SSDs, but I'm having some problems. I had to reinstall Windows 7 and created a partition for it, with the remaining volume (unallocated) being dedicated to the Ubuntu partition.

The Ubuntu installer, however, doesn't recognize that partition as free space - in fact, all it does is recognize the entire volume of 240gb from the raid 0, not being able to see the partitions. How do I proceed in this situation? I have an HDD here, but I wanted to install Ubuntu on my SSDs because of the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I can answer your question. The partition should not be unallocated. If you use Gparted, go to the program and right click on the unallocated button. Click "new". You will see a drop down menu. Select ntfs. I hope this helps.